# return the list value in model to controller where the list presents inside the bool class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the name and other details from the employee table, where the username and password presents, but I can't return the list value fetched from the database inside the bool function.

MY MODEL IS Login model class, where I just declare the model :

```
namespace BusinessLayer
{
    public class Login
    {
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UserType { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int ReportingToId { get; set; }
        public string ReportingTo { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

And my other model named LoginBusinessLayer class for the above model is:

```
namespace BusinessLayer
{
    public class LoginBusinessLayer
    {

        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public bool IsValid(string _username, string _password)
        {
            string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
            List<Login> login = new List<Login>();

            using (SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(cnn)) 
            {
                string _sql = @"SELECT *,AddUserType.UserType From Employee inner join AddUserType ON AddUserType.Id = Employee.UserTypeId " + 
                       @"WHERE [UserName] = @u AND [Password] = @p";
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(_sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters
                    .Add(new SqlParameter("@u", SqlDbType.VarChar))
                    .Value = _username;
                cmd.Parameters
                    .Add(new SqlParameter("@p", SqlDbType.VarChar))
                    .Value =_password;
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Login logi = new Login();

                    logi.EmployeeId = rdr["EmpId"].ToString();
                    logi.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();

                    logi.UserType = rdr["UserType"].ToString();
                    login.Add(logi);
                }
                return login; // HERE I WILL GET ERROR BECAUSE I CANT CONVERT LIST TO BOOL

                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    rdr.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    rdr.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

And My controller Class Named as Login :

```
namespace PMS_Rotary.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Login/
    [HttpGet]


        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Login(LoginBusinessLayer log)
    {

        string Name = "";
        string EmployeeId = "";
        string UserType = "";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (log.IsValid(log.UserName, log.Password))
            {
                List<Login> login = new List<Login>();
                foreach (var i in login)
                {

                    Name = i.Name;
                    EmployeeId = i.EmployeeId;
                    UserType = i.UserType;
                }
                Session["Name"] = Name;
                Session["EmployeeId"] = EmployeeId;

                Session["UserType"] = UserType;



                return RedirectToAction("Homepage","Homepage");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Credentials are invalid");
            }
        }
        return View(log);
    }

    }
}
```

This is my problem - the code correctly fetches all data using the list in model, but I can't return it inside the bool function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of improvements that could be made to your code. I'm only going to answer your question. The easiest solution would be to change your `IsValid` method to return the Login object rather than a bool. In your controller, if it's not null, you know the credentials are valid. You expect a `List<Login>`, which I don't understand (I assume there would be one or none returned from your sql query). You can then pass that Login object's id to your `Homepage` action and get rid of the nasty Session variables.

```
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = log.IsValid(log.UserName, log.Password);
        if(user != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Homepage","Homepage", new {id = user.EmployeeId});
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Credentials are invalid");
        }
    }
```

In your Homepage action, grab the id from the route and query the database for the corresponding login.

Suggestions: Your `Login` action should not take a `LoginBusinessLayer`. Change your `Login` class to have only those things related to a login (username and password). Create a separate class (Employee? User?) to hold the properties that are currently in your `Login` class. Take the code that is responsible for opening database connections and queries and put that in a separate class (EmployeeService?).

There are many other things that could be improved upon, but hopefully, this is a start.